# this context in ajax data option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have object with `data` array and `mark_read` method, which sends `PUT` request to my Rails app. It looks like `this` in `data` option is not the object instance, how can I fix it?

```
Notifications.prototype = {
  constructor: Notifications,
  ...
  mark_read: function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "PUT",
      url: '/notifications/mark_read',
      data: this.data.slice(0,5)
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to be? Where is data defined?

Answer (score 0):

You should store "this" in a closure before trying to access it from inside of $.ajax function.

It should be something like this

```
Notifications.prototype = {
  constructor: Notifications,
  ...
  mark_read: function() {
      var me = this;
      $.ajax({
          method: "PUT",
          url: '/notifications/mark_read',
          data: me.data.slice(0,5)
      });
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope for `this` is the `mark_read` function, so the context for `this` is whatever `Notification` object `mark_read()` is called upon.